# What is the best option to send data to another script without be blocked

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, listener, rcp

I have been working on two scripts where one of the script (we can call `generate_data.py`) that generates the data (looks for new data 24/7) and I have `notifications.py` that receives the data from `generate_data` , convert it to a json and post it to my server through a requests.

There is some problems that I have and one of them is that I need it to run simultaneously. That means whenever the `generate_data.py` is looking for new data, when it sends the data to `notifications.py` it should NOT wait for the `notifications.py` to be done. Instead it should work all the time and only send data to `notifications.py` when new found and continue looking for new data.

Scenario that can happen is that `generate_data.py` can get new 5 data at the same time and is needing to be send to `notifications.py` that needs to send the requests to my server as soon as possible without any delay/stopping/blocking.

I got few suggestions such as using `listener`, `queue`, `rcp`, `threading`, `multiprocessing` but here I am. My question is, What would be my best option to use here where I have `generate_data.py` that is on 24/7 and `notifications.py` should only post once it got the data from generate_data and post it to my server as fast as possible and without being blocked/stopped and if there is any example would also be appreciated it! (Using python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as generate_data script generates data and sends it to notification script, while notification script is in processing the data which has sent meanwhile the data generated by generate_data where you are storing it to push to the notification script later ?

you can do one thing as you asked only with python..
you can generate data in to a file always and notifications script read the content and delete only content which is read, so that you can do both parallel.

Comment: Correct as you mentioned. Generate_data script generates data and sends it to notification script. The generate_data will always try to find for new data and push it to notification if it finds new data and notifications will always get the data -> convert it to json (optional for now) and then push it to my server through requests.

Wouldn't it be an issue to have a file reader all the time, im thinking based on CPU/RAM that needs to do a check for new file all the time? That's why I thought maybe sort of listener could be good but maybe overkill?

Comment: yeah listener is also fine.. but i am saying to do operations with one file only.. both ways you can achieve. but with file you need to handle properly.. is there possibility for you to use apache kafka which is opensource ?

Comment: either to do with one file or maybe just look for all *.txt/*.json inside the folder could also work. unless you are thinking something else? I have no idea what apache kafka is but if its helpful for my problem then I probably could if it supports windows 10 and ubuntu